# How to create a custom inspector which can select object in scene > script > function (public void...)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

I the user to be able to select an object then a script which is within and then a void which is within the script.

So basically, inside the inspector of script1 I want to user to be able to select an object, then a script which is within it and then a void of the script.

The player has to select functions the same way as in UI button.
[image: What it should look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing such a Drawer for the Inspector yourself requires reflection and is quite complicated (see the [source code of `UnityEventDrawer`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/UnityEventDrawer.cs)).

---

Anyway, I guess you are actually talking about simply using your own [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) (That's exactly what the [`Button.onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) uses) in your script like e.g.

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent OnSomethingHappened;

    // And invoke it where needed
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) OnSomethingHappened?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. I am deeply sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: No worries, I understood it and am glad to help ;) Please feel free to mark the answer as accepted.